# SVG to Glyphs conversion

Tags: python, svg, glyph, fontforge, ttx-fonttools

Can anyone suggest any python library to convert svg into glyphs. I have used fonttools and font forge. Is there any other suggestion.I have tried fonttools and fontforge,I am using windows and fontforge doesn't work well with windows

Comment: Instead, can you talk about what you're _actually_ trying to do? Are you trying to create _a font_ where each glyph comes from a separate SVG file? Are you trying to edit an existing OpenType font with SVG table and you want to convert that to `glyf`+`loca` or CFF/CFF2? Take a bit of time and [describe your situation in detail](/help/how-to-ask): what are you trying to achieve, what solutions(s) did you find to do that, which of those did you try and what code did you write for that, how did those not do what you expected, and what debugging and (re)search did you do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: GlyphsLib is a Python library for reading, writing, and manipulating font files in the Glyphs file format. It can be used to convert SVG files into glyphs, among other operations.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, thanks for your reply, I am sorry I was unclear. I am trying to create a new font. I am taking an existing font as a base font and editing the glyphs within them. yes, all the glyphs come from separate SVG files. The base font is a .tff. I am fairly new to this, so I was wondering if this process is valid. if not, can you suggest any other process? thanks.

Comment: @ghost21blade, thank you, I am going to look into that.

Comment: Also note that https://typedrawers.com is usually a much better place to ask font related questions.